# make a GET request from a client side template using jquery

Tags: jquery, web-services, jersey

Im creating a webservice,using Jersey frame work.
i have a method which returns JSON array for as response for a GET call.
i have to call this WS from a HTML page using Jquery,
i have found some resources on the internet and got to know how i can call and render it in the html page.

lately,i seen this tutorial which shows how we can generate a client side template to automatically which we can use in the web broswer for a Spring based WS.

can some one help me to generate a similar template for all the WS methods which i have created in Jersey.

below is the link to the tutorial.
http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/021-consume-get-request-spring-rest-webservice-jquery/#the-template